# How to compare vector with array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, compare, containers

I would like to compare vector with an array. Elements in vector and in array are in different order, unsorted and can duplicated. E.g.

Below are the same:

```
vector<int> lvector = {5,7,3,1,2,7};
int larray[6] = {3,5,1,7,2,7}
```

Below, not the same:

```
vector<int> lvector = {5,7,3,1,2,7,5};
int larray[7] = {3,5,1,7,2,7,3}
```

And something like this is also not the same:

```
vector<int> lvector = {1,1,1,1,2,2};
int larray[6] = {1,1,1,1,1,2}
```

Now I need to check if vector and array have got the same elements. I can't modify the vector and the array, but I can create a new container and copy the element from vector and array to this new container and then copare them. I am asking about this, because I would like to do this in en efficient way. Thanks.

Comment: You should attempt it first and then when you run into problems, come and ask your specific question with the basis of your code as a jumping point for StackOverflow to assist in answering your question.

Comment: Fortunately, the C++ standard library have [many algorithmic functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) that can be used, for example to [check equality between two ranges](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) (though it requires both ranges to be in the same order). You could also use [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) with  a custom predicate to [find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) all value from one container in the other.

Comment: std::equal works when the elements in vector are unsorted: {5,7,3,1,2,7}?

Comment: @DekodererDekoderer It works if both containers are in the same *order*, and also size. If yours aren't then please read my (edited) comment again, and follow the links.

Comment: By the way, you are aware that you declare `larray` as an array of *five* elements, but try to initialize it with *six*?

Comment: Thanks. Of course it should be 6 - my mistake.

Comment: You could just remove the size from brackets - it will be calculated automatically.

Comment: Is there any reason not to sort both and then compare?

Comment: @Boris - from the post _I can't modify the vector and the array_

Comment: @MichaelAnderson From the post: _but I can create a new container and copy the element from vector and array to this new container and then copare them_

Comment: You can reduce unequal cases by sum each elements of vector (or calculate length of vector) .   
Sum(lv) = {1,1,1,1,2,2} = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 = 8  > Sum(array)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different ways of solving this problem, each has proc and cons.

### Some pre-tests

1. Obviously, two ranges cannot be equal, if they have different size.
2. You could calculate an order independent hash function for elements in the ranges (thanks, @Michael Anderson). It could be a sum of elements, or you just could `xor` them all. Arrays with different hash value cannot be equal.

### [`std::unordered_multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset)

You could create an `unordered_multiset`, which holds frequency of elements in the range. While it has linear complexity in average, it may be O(n^2) because of hash collisions. Quote from the Standard (N3337, § 23.5.7.2):

> Complexity: Average case linear, worst case quadratic.

However, you should also remember the complexity of `std::unordered_set::operator==`:

> For `unordered_set` and `unordered_map`, the complexity of
>   `operator==` (i.e., the number of calls to the `==` operator of the
>   `value_type`, to the predicate returned by `key_equal()`, and to the
>   hasher returned by `hash_function()`) is proportional to `N` in the
>   average case and to `N^2` in the worst case, where `N` is `a.size()`.
>
> For `unordered_multiset` and `unordered_multimap`, the complexity of
>   `operator==` is proportional to `sum of Ei^2` in the average case and
>   to `N^2` in the worst case, where `N` is `a.size()`, and `Ei` is the
>   size of the `i`th equivalent-key group in `a`.
>
> However, if the
>   respective elements of each corresponding pair of equivalent-key
>   groups `Eai` and `Ebi` are arranged in the same order (as is commonly
>   the case, e.g., if `a` and `b` are unmodified copies of the same
>   container), then the average-case complexity for `unordered_multiset`
>   and `unordered_multimap` becomes proportional to `N` (but worst-case
>   complexity remains `O(N2)`, e.g., for a pathologically bad hash
>   function).

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{5, 7, 3, 1, 2, 7};
    int arr[] = {3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 7};

    std::unordered_multiset<int> mv(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    std::unordered_multiset<int> ma(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));

    std::cout << "Are equal? " << (mv == ma) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

You could compare sorted copies of your range. According to the Standard (N3337, § 25.4.1.1) , it has `O(n * log(n))` complexity:

> Complexity: O(N log(N)) (where N == last - first) comparisons.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{5, 7, 3, 1, 2, 7};
    int arr[] = {3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 7};

    std::vector<int> sv(v);
    std::vector<int> sa(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));

    std::sort(std::begin(sv), std::end(sv));
    std::sort(std::begin(sa), std::end(sa));

    std::cout << "Are equal? " << (sv == sa) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you care about speed there's a couple of improvements that nicely sit above this. 1. If they have different lengths then they can't be equal. 2. If they have different sums (or bitwise xors, or products, etc) they cant be equal. These can be big gains since these tests are `O(n)` while the construction of the multiset is `O(n log(n))`

Comment: i.e. you should use the cheep O(n) and O(1) tests to rule out cases where they can never be equal before you bother constructing the multisets.

Comment: @Michael: This is O(n) too. You're thinking `multiset`, not `unordered_multiset`.

Comment: @Hurkyl - you may be right (can't find the reference for that) - but either way scanning and operating on the lists is likely to be significantly faster than constructing another data structure.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson, Yes, you are right, thank you. I'm just looking at the standard for the complexity of constructing `std::unorederd_multiset`, which should be O(n). As soon as I find, I will update the answer with reference to your suggestions.

Comment: Using vector means better use of cache.

Answer (score 2):

That's a variant of what proposed by soon:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{5, 7, 3, 1, 2, 7};
    int arr[] = {3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 7};

    std::vector<int> mv(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    std::vector<int> ma(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
    std::sort(mv.begin(), mv.end()) ;
    std::sort(ma.begin(), ma.end()) ;

    std::cout << "Are equal? " << (mv == ma) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's good solution, but it will take time complexity O(nlogn) - because of sorting. Maybe there is faster solution like unordered_multiset, or map.

Comment: Are the other soution faster? For map you have an O(nlogn) build time, while unordered_multiset is faster to build but slower to compare (at least according to cppreference.com)

Comment: @DekodererDekoderer You need to profile different solutions with realistic array sizes. `multiset` and `unordered_multiset` will result in more dynamic allocations so are not necessarily "faster" (beware of confusing complexity with speed.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is template function to compare `vector` with `array`:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template <class T, std::size_t N>
bool equal(const std::vector<T>& v, const std::array<T, N>& a)
{
    if (v.size() != N)
        return false;
        
    return std::equal(v.begin(), v.end(), a.begin());
}
```

Usage example:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
std::array<int, 4> a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    
bool eq = equal(v, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

At first convert the array into v1 vector.

v={1,1,2,3,4};    vector and

v1={1,1,2,3,4}; converted from array

```
bool f=0;
if(equal(v.begin(),v.end(),v1.begin()))  //compare two vector, if equal return true
{
    f=1;
}

}
if(f==1)
    cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
else cout<<"No"<<endl;
```

Comment: No need to convert. You can call std::begin on an array.